# Just to Update and Upgrade in terminal

Tags: bash, sh

so what i want to do is to create a shell script to update and upgrade for that i just created an .sh file in which there are three lines of command

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

after running .sh file it executes just fine.
but what i want to do more with it is - after successfully running update command and while running upgrade command it ask us to get the archive with 'Y/N'.
can i do something in .sh so that i don't have to type 'y' or 'n' . i want y to be default.

Comment: See `help read`.

Comment: did you try to add `-y` option ?

Comment: In general, you can often simply do `yes | cmd`.  Indeed, that is the purpose of the `yes` command. But when the command has `-y` option (or similar) available, you should use it.

Answer (score 0):

On a debian based installation on Raspberry i using the short form of IF THEN ELSE like this...

```
apt update && apt -y full-upgrade || echo 'Hm, something failed!'
```

...and "The Matrix" asking nothing.